# Getting old OS versions on the Xcode iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Every simulator that I have on Xcode runs on version 8.4 but I want to test on iOS 6 and 7.

I've done what this answer recommends: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8477254/1282637

However, when I go to Xcode -> preferences - downloads, the only non-iOS 8 version available is 7.1:

[image]

Is there a way I can download an iOS 6.x.x simulator? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to support iOS 6 at this time?

Comment: @rmaddy is it standard practice to drop iOS support at this point? I'm only trying to target my biggest audience and I'm not using iOS 7+ specific features

Comment: Most people are using iOS 8 and soon iOS 9. There's little reason to support even iOS 7 now with a new app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Xcode 6` , `iOS simulator` for `iOS version 6.x` seems to be `deprecated`.

Apple deprecates old technologies very aggressively. Formaly saying, you should deprecate support for older version of OSes such as 6.x.

If the Xcode doesn't provide older version of simulator, the only way to do this is to install older version of Xcode.

[download older Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839526/where-to-download-older-xcode-versions)

Currently you can just use `Xcode 5.x`.

Comment: Why post an answer and flag the question as a duplicate?

Comment: is it possible to run ios5 simulator in Xcode7.3?Please help me

Comment: @Jasper - you need to install xcode 6 for this

Comment: But i am using mac 0S 10.12.I want to work with Xcode7.3.1 and this also support iOS5 to iOS9 simulator