# How to run ios 8.4.1 device into xcode 6.0.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, ios-simulator

i can't access my device 
My Device Version is->8.4.1

My Xcode deployment Version is ->8.0(maximum version),when i try to run its give me error message **[may be running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of Xcode]**.

Is there any possibility to run my device.

Comment: Try with XCode 6.4 that you could be able to download on the Apple Dev Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running iOS 8.4.1 on your phone/simulator, then you'll need to upgrade to Xcode **6.4**, which contains the iOS 8.4 SDK.

Comment: so no other way to connect my device i am correct bro @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: ya sure my bro at the same time ref this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675142/getting-old-os-versions-on-the-xcode-ios-simulator/32675219#32675219) also

Comment: @KishoreKumar -- in every Xcode support some limited version if it is exceed we need to upgrade our Xcode , got it

Comment: @Anbu.Kathik bro there

Comment: @KishoreKumar -- what I do for u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90209/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-anbu-karthik).