# Xcode 12 - Download more simulators runtime is empty

Tags: xcode, xcode12

I can't add more simulator OS version in XCode 12, for example iOS 13, the list is empty:[image]

[image]

how can I add more simulatore with different ios version?

Comment: What system version are you using? Is this Catalina? Is it the latest Catalina? Is it Big Sur beta? Is it the latest Big Sur beta? Exactly what version of Xcode? Did you try the new Xcode beta?

Comment: Xcode Version 12.0.1, MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: I have Xcode 12 and Catalina and I see simulators. I don’t know what 12.0.1 is, I don’t see it at the dev center

Comment: Same problem here. xCode `12.0.1 (12A7300)` - macOS Catalina `10.15.6 (19G2021)`

Comment: Same problem with `12.0.1`

Comment: I upgraded to 12 through the application, and also had downloaded a compressed archive file of the entire version 12 application.  The current installation suffered from the defect.  I tried to look inside the compressed archive file, and it (apparently) installed-over my installed version, and also repopulated the list of simulators.

Comment: had the same problem, after rebooting os (big sur) the list magically re-appeared

Answer (score 12):

I had exact same problem, apple returns empty list of simulators. Here is what I did:

1. First install xcode-install gem ([follow readme](https://github.com/xcpretty/xcode-install)):

   ```
   $ gem install xcode-install
   ```
2. Then check what iOS simulators are available:

   ```
   $ xcversion simulators
   ```
3. Finally install desired simulator i.e:

   ```
   $ xcversion simulators --install='iOS 13.5'
   ```

Comment: I had to run `gem install xcode-install --user-install` to get around the write permission error.  Then it doesn't work when I type `xcversion simulators` (command not found).  I looked and see there might be an dependency on `fastlane` as well?  Not quite a 3 step process after all.

Comment: @Dale added link to `xcode-install` readme, there some notes added on install. However for me it was as easy as running `gem install`

Comment: after `gem install xcode-install`, when I run `xcversion simulators` it only shows ```$ xcversion simulators
Xcode 12.1 (/Applications/Xcode.app)```

Comment: if facing file write issue then follow the second anser on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550903/why-do-i-get-a-permission-denied-error-while-installing-a-gem to resolve file write issue

Answer (score 8):

I had similar problem. As I remember in older Xcode easy option to add devices. in Xcode 12.X you can just go to `Xcode -> Preference -> Component -> Select OS`

See below 
[image: Preferences tool]

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the platform for the phones from settings.

Xcode > settings > platforms > ios version

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by going to the apple developer download page https://developer.apple.com/download/ and downloading the XCode 12.2 beta.

I threw my other version of XCode in the trash. I was able to see all the normal iOS simulator runtimes that are missing from your screenshot.

Update: It appears that the issue is resolved in Xcode 12.2 Beta 2.

Comment: As an update, I opened xcode 12.2 beta again today, and now the runtime list is empty there too. No idea what to do

Comment: You might consider deleting the answer, since you proved it doesn't work :)

Comment: I reinstalled 12.0.1 and it is now repopulating the list.  I'm not sure how long it will last, but it's there after reinstalling.