# Nativescript application not showing console.log messages in terminal

Tags: angular, nativescript

I create a new nativescript application (ns create xxxx) and then run it to get it loaded into a simulator (ns run ios).

Once running, I add a console log anywhere (on init, or as an action from a button click etc.) and it will not output to the console.

I have found a thread on Stack that posed a similar question but it looks like they never got much feedback (and others reported the issue).

I have tried running in the VSCode terminal as well as the regular terminal (so it's not a VSCode thing).  I am completely floored on what could be causing this.

Comment: If you're expecting the logs to show up in Chrome dev tools (which I suspect you are), you'll not find it there. Look in the terminal you're running the app from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks strange because `console.log`s usually work ok. Please check the following

1. Be sure that you **do not** run your application in release mode or with `--env.uglify` flag because it may cause drop logging
2. Disable hot module replacement option. Sometimes it cause issues.
3. Be sure to use correct `console` operations. For example `console.debug` is not supported. You can find full list [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/console)
4. Remove `node_modules`, `platforms` and `hooks` folders before next run. Just in case.
5. Don't you have `console` object overridden by some other object?
6. Try to change your `console.log` command with `alert` and check if it works.

Please, come back after your check all the points from this checklist, also please add the report from your `ns doctor` command, and let's see if we can move on

**Update:**

Since you're using MacBook based on M1 processor it seems that your question is related to this issue:

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/5454

Unfortunately, the only advice I can give you for now is to follow the thread for some solution or workarounds

Comment: Ok, so I'm not (actively) running in release mode.  I tried runnning with HMR off and same behavior.  I am only trying console.log("hello");  I don't know what you mean by having the console object overridden but as I mentioned, I've done this from a fresh (ns create) project.  Finally I have used alert instead of console.log and I do get the alert without an issue.  NS Doctor shows all good.  Only additional information I can provide is that I'm on a new computer that I just bought (macbook pro).  So it's freshly installed everything (VSCode, nativescript, node, etc.)

Comment: ok, try to remove `node_modules`, `platforms` and `hooks` folders before the next run and change `console.log` to `alert` to see if this line of code is really called

Comment: Is your MacBook based on an M1 processor?

Comment: Yes, it's an M1.  I had to install node twice (once under ARM and again under Darwin).  But I have everything else working as best I can tell.  The app launches in the simulator it just doesn't show any console.log messages.  I did remove the above folders (via ns clean) and rebuilt...tried with Alert and it works, tried with console.log and nothing

Comment: Seems your problem is related to https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/5454. Follow this thread for some updates or workarounds. That's all I can help for now, unfortunately. In case you find a solution that helps, I appreciate if you share it with me.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  So it must be related to that.  I tried the command provided in the thread to log to a different terminal (the log stream command) and that does show my logs although I didn't follow how to 'pipe it to sed/awk' as instructed.  But it does show something.

Comment: Final comment on this, rolling back to a previous iOS version on the simulator does show the messages.  This link shows how to do that:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262018/xcode-simulator-how-to-run-older-ios-version#:~:text=To%20run%20an%20older%20iOS,and%20to%203.2%20for%20iPad.

Answer (score 2):

I'm joining in a bit later, but this might help someone else who's having the same issue while also using the M1 based processors.

For me, using `console.log()` *(on iOS)* didn't show any output in Visual Studio Code, but it did show up in a separate Xcode build. So the output is definitely out there.

I came across a SO answer a while ago *(don't remember which one exactly)* that had this workaround which shows the output in a separate terminal window.

**Suppose we have this:**
[image]

Open a new terminal window *(preferably outside of VS Code. You'll see why in a second)*, and run this command:

`log stream --level debug --predicate 'senderImagePath contains "NativeScript"'`

It'll show the output in the terminal window as shown below:

[image]

Now, I honestly think this would be easier to read *(especially when you're logging JSON data on a smaller screen)* if everything in between the timestamp and "CONSOLE LOG" was excluded. Unfortunately I haven't figured out how to do that yet.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing the `Vue.config.silent` which is by default set to `true` to `false`.

You can add `Vue.config.silent = false;` inside your `app.js` before `new Vue(...)`

Ex:

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue'

import Home from './components/Home'

Vue.config.silent = false;

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h('frame', [h(Home)]),
}).$start()
```

Happy coding!

Comment: This helped me when migrating from nativescript 7 to nativescript 8

Comment: I'm happy it did! :)