# How to Support Below IOS 4.3 in Xcode 4.5.2?

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

My iMac Version is 10.8.2,installed Xcode 4.5.2. Xcode project iOS Deployment target is 4.3, and Base SDK iOS 6.0. I am trying develop an application which can be run from 3G. Base SDK showing only IOS 6.0 but not listing any lower versions, also installed iPhone 5.0 simulator. 
but no use.

Following are my questions
1) How Xcode will show Base SDK lower versions than IOS 6.0?
2) How we can can support Different IOS versions?

Please let me know the right direction,, Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747432/how-to-build-against-older-ios-versions-with-the-latest-xcode-downloads).

It explains how to publish to older iOS targets.