# Migration project to iOS 7 required or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, ios7

I have project which was developed iOS 6 and when I install it on device with iOS7 it's looks good. But now I update xcode to 5th version and now it's look not so fine. I know about application migration. My question is will I have some problems if I will continue using xcode 4 and upload to Apple will be targeted to iOS 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your iOS 6 app runs in a compatability mode when run on iOS 7. You can currently submit apps compiled with older versions of Xcode but they will stop accepting them at some point -- and probably quite soon.

To directly answer you question: no, you don't have to update *now*. But assuming you will want to maintain the app for more than another couple of months it's some work you'll have to schedule.

*Update*: [Apple will require](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a#top) new and updated apps to be compiled with Xcode 5 from February 1 2014, around four months after iOS 7 came out.

Comment: I had the the screen to upgrade. I clicked skip. Is there anyway that I can manually migrate it. I am looking in xCode but didn't see any option for migration.

Answer (score 1):

You are fine with Xcode 4 -- for now. But I would advise to get familiar with the iOS 7 SDK and Xcode 5 as soon as possible.

You did not explain why "it's look not so fine". Just set the target OS to 6.0, and it should really behave exactly the same way, maybe with a couple of more warnings.

Comment: I am arrived a bit later, so I can only confirm what you already say. Also, I really did not know about the app behaving the same if compiled with older version.

Answer (score 1):

I have left a project on the App Store, compiled with iOS 5.

With my surprise (I did not know about that) I found out that the App, running on iOS 7 device looks perfectly fine, without all the problem of elements positioning, just as it was on an iOS 5/6 device. Even the keyboard is displayed old style.

On the contrary if I run with a simulator, everything is messed up. So I choose to leave as it is, and plan a layout upgrade in the nearest future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use 4.
You want you can build against an older sdk with 5.

[How to build against older iOS versions with the latest Xcode downloads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747432/how-to-build-against-older-ios-versions-with-the-latest-xcode-downloads)