# How to make apps support an earlier iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store

I recently just released a very simple game on the app store. However, it requires iOS 8.4. How do I make it so that it supports iOS 6 & 7? I am using Swift and SpriteKit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build against older iOS versions with the latest Xcode downloads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747432/how-to-build-against-older-ios-versions-with-the-latest-xcode-downloads)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for support earlier iOS 6 & 7 you need to worried about two thing:

**First is Deployment target:**

[image]

Deployment target is use for setting minimum iOS support. so using that you can make you application support for older iOS version.

**Second thing is worried about it's API**

Apple are remove some API support with new API for iOS8 and iOS9. You can find some list [iOS 7.1 to iOS 8.0 API Differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014455) and you can check diffrent also from [change log iOS9](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html)

if you are support older iOS version then you need to set check with some api is not working in ios7 for example `UIVisualEffectView` that is introduced from iOS8 so you need to check in iOS7 code with if else or other way that API is suport for iOS7 or not. else your app will be crash in iOS7 device.

Hope that information will be help to you.